# Convert Tesseract Character List to CSV in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, csv, tesseract

I want to convert the following list using the Tesseract Library in R to a CSV file, using the /n to create a new row, and white space to create a new cell/column:

"5 2 3 390 - 500 -\n8 50 & 3 3 887 7\n1 3 - 9 5\n"

I can read in the scanned PDF, create the character list, but whenever I output it to file, the CSV only has one cell for each line with all of the characters in that line/row contained in one cell.

So far I have used the following code:

```
library(tesseract)
eng <- tesseract("eng")
tesseract_text <- tesseract::ocr(image = file.choose(), engine = eng)
write.table(x = tesseract_text, file = "C:/Temp/tess_text.csv")
```

I have tried many other combinations of writing tables, converting to data frame, converting white space to comma then output, but nothing seems to work. I was expecting to have each character string contained before white space in its own cell, every white space to represent a new cell, and the \n to delineate a new row in Excel, but the only thing that seems to work is the \n to start a new row.

Comment: you are writing to `csv`. Consider writing to `txt`. Or change the separator to `,` when writing to `csv`

Comment: I need the data to be in Excel and be separated by column, and I have tried adjusting the "sep" parameter.

Comment: Thats why i said use comma as u=your separator. ie `write.table(...., sep = ', ')`

Comment: It will only apply the "," to the first line using the above code and using comma as the sep parameter if outputting to .txt using write.table.

Comment: output should be csv. You need tou use `write.table(..., sep = ',', file = "..csv")`

Comment: Do you have a list/dataframe or strings??

Comment: It is a list, but if I convert to data.frame it still only applies the comma to the first element and not all. I think I need to use a lapply here maybe with gsub, but not sure where to go...

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Try `write.table(head(iris), sep=",")` and you will see that it applys the comma to all the spaces.

Comment: I figured out why it is applying the comma to only the first element in each row. The dataframe has a dim of 34, 1, but there are many more than 1 column, it is just that the dimensions for each row don't have the same amount of columns (as I am reading in a large pdf with lots of data), so I think I will need to split up each row, process, output and append. Does this make sense, and how would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(stringr)

text <- "5 2 3 390 - 500 -\n8 50 & 3 3 887 7\n1 3 - 9 5\n"
text_By_Row <- stringr::str_split(text, pattern = "\n")[[1]]
nb_Row <- length(text_By_Row)
text_By_Cell <- stringr::str_split(text_By_Row, pattern = " ")

for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
{
  if(length(text_By_Cell[[i]]) < 7)
  {
    text_By_Cell[[i]] <- c(text_By_Cell[[i]], rep("", 7 - length(text_By_Cell[[i]])))
  }
}

mat_Data <- do.call("rbind", text_By_Cell)
mat_Data

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6]  [,7]
[1,] "5"  "2"  "3"  "390" "-"  "500" "-" 
[2,] "8"  "50" "&"  "3"   "3"  "887" "7" 
[3,] "1"  "3"  "-"  "9"   "5"  ""    ""  
[4,] ""   ""   ""   ""    ""   ""    ""  

write.csv(mat_Data, file = "mat_Data.csv")
```